# Implicit Conversion dependent on

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I restored StackOverFlow 2013 DB as per https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/. I restored it on Sql Server 2017 dev edition and compatibility level is set to 2017.

In the user Table, I noticed something which I am not able to understand. For some index combination, I am getting CONVERT_IMPLICIT but for some I am not seeing CONVERT_IMPLICIT. Please refer to attached screenshot for detail.

[image]

Comment: Aside: The mystery should be why try to check the value of an `int` column (`age`) against a Unicode string (`N'20'`).

Comment: Can you include the datatypes of the age columns in the 3 tables?